# Why this JavaScript RegExp results in dual answer?

Tags: javascript, regex

Look at this simple HTML `input` tag:

```
<input type='text' id='phoneNumber' name='phoneNumber' class='inputBig textLeft'
data-validation='required regex' 
data-validation-regex-pattern='^\\+\\d{2}\\.\\d{10}$'
value='+98.2188665544' />

<p id='log'></p>
```

Now imagine that we want to validate this field, using this function:

```
var log = $('#log');
function validateRegex(field) {
    var pattern = field.attr('data-validation-regex-pattern');
    log.append(pattern + '<br />');
    if (pattern && pattern != '') {
        var isValid = new RegExp(pattern).test(field.val().trim());
        if (!isValid) {
            log.append('not valid<br />');
        }
        else {
            log.text('valid<br />');
        }
    }
}
validateRegex($('#phoneNumber'));
var isValid = new RegExp('^\\+\\d{2}\\.\\d{10}$').test($('#phoneNumber').val());
log.append(isValid.toString());
```

Now, if you look at the log, you see that this line returns false:

```
var isValid = new RegExp(pattern).test(field.val().trim());
```

However, this line of code returns true:

```
new RegExp('^\\+\\d{2}\\.\\d{10}$').test($('#phoneNumber').val().trim());
```

In other words, when the pattern of the `RegExp` object is passed to it as a string variable, it doesn't work. But when you pass a string literal, it works.

Why? What's wrong here?

To see it in action, look at this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/saeedneamati/GRL2m/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Escaping backslashes applies only to JavaScript, it isn't necessary for HTML.  Therefore, the following attribute string:

```
data-validation-regex-pattern='^\+\d{2}\.\d{10}$'
```

Will work just fine:

> **Updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/AndyE/GRL2m/6/**

Comment: But in C#, whenever you want to declare strings, you should escape them. I don't understand it. Do you say that when JavaScript gets the value of an HTML control, it doubles the slashes behind the seen?

Comment: @Saeed: no, I'm saying that it doesn't need to. Each character in the HTML attribute is *literal*, backslashes aren't considered *special* and do not need to be escaped. Even in C#, if you fetch a string from a HTML attribute you do not need to escape the slashes. Compare it to reading a string from a text file. You wouldn't expect to be required to escape every backslash in a text file before reading it into a C# or JavaScript string, would you?

Answer (score 1):

`\\` is the method to write `\` in a JavaScript String. The HTML data-attribute, written in JS would be `\\\\`, instead of `\\`.

Eg: `<a data-x="\\">`(HTML) is equivalent to `'<a data-x="\\\\">'` (JS).

To get your code work, replace double slashes (`\\`) in your HTML by a single slash.
**Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/GRL2m/5/**

Extra information:

- In HTML, HTML entities (eg `&quot;`) are used to display special characters.
- In JavaScript, escapes (eg `\n`, `\x20`, `\u0009`, ..) are used to display special characters.
- In a RegExp, special RE characters have to be escaped by a slash (`/\./`). When the RegExp is constructed using a string, the slash has to be escaped, so that the slash also appear at the RegExp. `"\." equals '.'`, while `"\\." equals '\.'`.

Comment: Didn't work. Test it on the fiddle. :(. Also note that `new RegExp` escapes them. Thus `\\.` simply for `new RegExp` means `\.`.

Comment: @SaeedNeamati See the bottom of my answer for a detailled explanation.